# How to use LinqPad with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linqpad

I feel like I've missed something obvious.

I want to test my EF Core `DbContext` in LinqPad like I usually do with regular EF.

I have a simple `DbContext`:

```
public class NotificationManagerContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }        
}
```

I've registered it in LinqPad using the new EF Core 2.0.1 driver:

[image]
But what next?

In an MCV Core app I'd register EF and the SQL driver in the app builder and pass it a connection string.  I don't see how to do the same config in LinqPad?

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold, that did the trick.  If you want to post that as an answer I will upvote and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linqpad there is no dependency injection framework running. So if you want to use a context there you could add a constructor that accepts a connection string. You can store the connection string in a member variable —say, `_connString`— and in the `OnConfiguring` override of the context do

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_connString)) 
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connString);
}
```

That gives you all freedom to play with database connections without having to leave Linqpad.